# Are games auto-balanced when playing private matches on COD WW2?

Tags: call-of-duty-ww2

If I create a private match on COD WW2 and all players have team auto-assign, will the game try to balance the players based on their stats/ranking/whatever or will they be randomly placed on axis/allies?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have tested this a while back in a full COD ww2 weekend with friends and I can say that no balancing can be found in the auto-assign. It was purely random.

There is no mention anywhere about such functionality.